# Get specific json data in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I'm using a API that gets a list of the crew from a movie. To get that i'm using this function:

```
MovieMDB.credits(apiKey, movieID: movieID){
            apiReturn, credits in
            if let credits = credits{
                for crew in credits.crew{
                    print(crew.job)
                    print(crew.name)

                }

            }
        }
```

This prints a list of jobs and crew members. But I only want the producer of this movie.

The function that's called:

```
  ///Get the cast and crew information for a specific movie id.
  public  class func credits(_ api_key: String!, movieID: Int!, completion: @escaping (_ clientReturn: ClientReturn, _ credits: MovieCreditsMDB?) -> ()) -> (){
    Client.Movies(String(movieID) + "/credits", api_key: api_key, page: nil, language: nil){
      apiReturn in
      var credits: MovieCreditsMDB?
      if(apiReturn.error == nil){
        credits = MovieCreditsMDB.init(results: apiReturn.json!)
      }
      completion(apiReturn, credits)
    }
  }
```

This is the beginning of the json file:

```
{
  "id": 550,
  "cast": [
    {
      "cast_id": 4,
      "character": "The Narrator",
      "credit_id": "52fe4250c3a36847f80149f3",
      "gender": 2,
      "id": 819,
      "name": "Edward Norton",
      "order": 0,
      "profile_path": "/eIkFHNlfretLS1spAcIoihKUS62.jpg"
    },
```

Here is the data I want:

```
"crew": [
    {
      "credit_id": "56380f0cc3a3681b5c0200be",
      "department": "Writing",
      "gender": 0,
      "id": 7469,
      "job": "Screenplay",
      "name": "Jim Uhls",
      "profile_path": null
    },
    {
      "credit_id": "52fe4250c3a36847f8014a05",
      "department": "Production",
      "gender": 0,
      "id": 7474,
      "job": "Producer",
      "name": "Ross Grayson Bell",
      "profile_path": null
```

I need the name of the producer. Does someone know how to get that specific data?
[Link to json](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-movie-credits) go to responses > example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to filter the result and only use/return the one that you want.

Once you have the list of all credits, just look for the one with the job of producer

```
 MovieMDB.credits(apiKey, movieID: movieID){
        apiReturn, credits in

        var producer: [String:AnyObject]?
        if let credits = credits {
            for crew in credits.crew {
                if crew.job == "Producer" {
                     producer = crew
                     break
                }
            }
        }
        // here check producer is not nil to ensure it was found
    }
```

you could also shorten this code using filter:

```
MovieMDB.credits(apiKey, movieID: movieID){
    apiReturn, credits in


    if let credits = credits {
        let producer = credits.filter({ $0.job == "Producer" })
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: Cannot sign value of type 'crewMDB' to type [String : AnyObject]?. This happens on the producer = crew line.

Comment: I wasn't sure on the types being returned, may need some slight modification